# Present View Controller when the view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: xcode

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import AVKit

class Class1: UIViewController {


var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
var playerView = AVPlayer()
var playerTimer = NSTimer()


override func viewDidAppear(animated:Bool) {
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "file.mp4")

    playerView = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)

    playerViewController.player = playerView

    self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true){
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
        self.playerTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4.0, target: self, selector:Selector("stopAfter4seconds:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

}
func stopAfter4seconds(timer: NSTimer){
    self.playerViewController.player?.pause()
    self.playerViewController.player = nil
    self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    self.presentViewController(GameViewController1(), animated: false, completion: nil)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()


}
```

}

My Problem is that when I present the line:

```
self.presentViewController(GameViewController1(), animated: false, completion: nil)
```

I Get the error "attempt to present GameViewController1... whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

I made sure to play it in viewDidAppear as to add it to the view hierarchy but it doesn't seem to do so

[Update] Okay i realize now that I'm presenting the avplayerviewcontroller and then trying to play the next view controller after. How exactly do I "Dismiss" the AVplayerviewcontroller as well have my next view in the right window hierarchy???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: I was presenting my next view with 'self.' instead of with the view controller that was present, which happened to be the playerViewController so this line of code worked for me.

```
playerViewController.presentViewController(GameViewController1(), 
animated: false, completion: nil)
```